# beautifulsoup выделяет не тот div

Tags: python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup

Пытаюсь спарсить со страницы этот код:

```html
<div class="sc-container">
<div class="sc-table sc-table-day">
<div class="sc-table-row">
<div class="sc-table-col sc-day-header sc-gray" >01.09<span class="sc-day">Сб</span></div>
        
<div class="sc-table-col sc-table-detail-container">
     <div class="sc-table sc-table-detail">
               
     <div class="sc-table-row"> 
     <!--<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-order"></div>-->
     <div class="sc-table-col sc-item-time">09:00 &ndash; 10:30</div>
     <div class="sc-table-col sc-item-period"></div>
     <div class="sc-table-col sc-item-type">ПЗ</div>
     <div class="sc-table-col sc-item-title">
     <div class="sc-item-title-body">
     <span class="sc-title">Физическая культура</span>
</div>
</div>
           
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-location"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker">&nbsp;</span>--каф.</div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-location-icon hidden-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span></div>
</div>
               
<div class="sc-table-row"> 
<!--<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-order"></div>-->
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-time">10:45 &ndash; 12:15</div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-period"></div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-type">ПЗ</div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-title">
<div class="sc-item-title-body">
<span class="sc-title">Экономика</span>
            
<br/><a href="/education/schedule/ppc.php?guid=f0ef1664-1d9a-11e0-9baf-1c6f65450efa"><span class="sc-lecturer">Сергеева Ирина Анатольевна</a></span></div>
</div>
           
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-location"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker">&nbsp;</span>3-405</div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-location-icon hidden-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span></div>
</div>
               
<div class="sc-table-row"> 
<!--<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-order"></div>-->
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-time">13:00 &ndash; 14:30</div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-period"></div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-type">ЛК</div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-title">
<div class="sc-item-title-body">
<span class="sc-title">Экономика</span>
            
<br/><a href="/education/schedule/ppc.php?guid=f0ef1664-1d9a-11e0-9baf-1c6f65450efa"><span class="sc-lecturer">Сергеева Ирина Анатольевна</a></span>        </div>
</div>
           
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-location"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker">&nbsp;</span>24Б-330</div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-location-icon hidden-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span></div>
          </div>
               
<div class="sc-table-row"> 
<!--<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-order"></div>-->
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-time">14:45 &ndash; 16:15</div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-period"></div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-type">ЛК</div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-title">
<div class="sc-item-title-body">
<span class="sc-title">Вычислительная техника и информационные технологии</span>
            
<br/><a href="/education/schedule/ppc.php?guid=5eb7efeb-1d99-11e0-9baf-1c6f65450efa"><span class="sc-lecturer">Щеглов Александр Васильевич</a></div>
</div>
           
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-location"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker">&nbsp;</span>24Б-330</div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-location-icon hidden-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>   
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Но парсер выдает:

```html
<div class="sc-container">
<div class="sc-table sc-table-day">
<div class="sc-table-row">
<div class="sc-table-col sc-day-header sc-gray">01.09<span class="sc-day">Сб</span></div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-table-detail-container">
<div class="sc-table sc-table-detail">
<div class="sc-table-row">
<!--<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-order"></div>-->
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-time">09:00 – 10:30</div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-period"></div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-type">ПЗ</div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-title">
<div class="sc-item-title-body">
<span class="sc-title">Физическая культура</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-location"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"> </span>--каф.</div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-location-icon hidden-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span></div>
</div>
<div class="sc-table-row">
<!--<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-order"></div>-->
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-time">10:45 – 12:15</div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-period"></div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-type">ПЗ</div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-title">
<div class="sc-item-title-body">
<span class="sc-title">Экономика</span>
<br><a href="/education/schedule/ppc.php?guid=f0ef1664-1d9a-11e0-9baf-1c6f65450efa"><span class="sc-lecturer">Сергеева Ирина Анатольевна</span></a></br></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

То есть, только часть кода

Сам парсер:

```
request = requests.get(target_url)
html_page = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "html.parser")
table_row = html_page.find_all('div', 'sc-container')
```

Проблемы у меня, сайта или bs?
UPD:
Я так понял, что bs по непонятной причине закрывает все теги и в конце ставит , после чего продолжает читать документ:

```
    <br>
                 <a href="/education/schedule/ppc.php?guid=f0ef1664-1d9a-11e0-9baf-1c6f65450efa">
                  <span class="sc-lecturer">
                   Сергеева Ирина Анатольевна
                  </span>
                 </a>
                </br>
               </div>
              </div>
             </div>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-location">
```

Я так понял, что это из-за незакрытого тега

UPD 1:
Попытался удалить. decompose не работает или что-то совсем не так

```
$ html_page.br.decompose()
$ html_page.find_all('br')
[<br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>,<br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>]
```

Comment: Опишите, что вы хотите именно спарсить, какие элементы

Comment: Я хочу спарсить <div class="sc-container">

Comment: Попробуйте другой парсер в bs4, например lxml

Comment: А лучше дайте ссылку на ресурс, я сам посмотрю

Comment: https://mai.ru/education/schedule/detail.php?group=%D0%9C4%D0%9E-311%D0%91-16

Comment: Добавил ответ. Если не секрет для чего вам данные? Мобильную приложку сделать?

Comment: Я бота для телеграмма дописываю, уже второй год работает, но они разметку сайта редактировали летом, вот и проблемы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте парсер lxml, html.parser ошибается.

```
url = 'https://mai.ru/education/schedule/detail.php?group=%D0%9C4%D0%9E-311%D0%91-16'
request = requests.get(url)
html_page = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "lxml")
table_row = html_page.find_all('div', 'sc-container')
print(table_row[0])
```

Результат проблемного участка:

```
<span class="sc-title">Экономика</span>
<br/><a href="/education/schedule/ppc.php?guid=f0ef1664-1d9a-11e0-9baf-1c6f65450efa"><span class="sc-lecturer">Сергеева Ирина Анатольевна</span></a> </div>
</div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-location"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"> </span>3-405</div>
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-location-icon hidden-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span></div>
</div>
<div class="sc-table-row">
<!--<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-order"></div>-->
<div class="sc-table-col sc-item-time">13:00 – 14:30</div>
```

Comment: А не известно, почему так?

Comment: На самом деле должен lxml ошибаться, так как более подходит для разбора xml, html.parser всегда отрабатывал нормально, но в этот раз почему-то наоборот. Можно вообще на lxml переписать, без использования Beautiful Soup

Comment: Но всё-таки: что не так со страницей?